# I'm trying to use arithmatic on trigger, but my Trigger doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, database-trigger

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER afterPembelian
AFTER INSERT ON pembelian

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE harga INT(20);
DECLARE total INT(20);

SELECT harga_obat INTO harga FROM daftar_obat WHERE kode_obat=NEW.kodeobat;

IF(DAYNAME(NEW.tanggal_pem)='Monday') THEN
    total = (harga-harga/10)*NEW.jml_beli;
ELSE 
    total = harga * NEW.jml_beli;
END IF;

SELECT * FROM daftar_obat;
SELECT * FROM pembelian;
SELECT total;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= (harga-harga/10)*NEW.jml_beli;
>   ELSE
>       total = harga * NEW.jml_beli;
>   END IF;' at line 11

Comment: total =  this syntax is incorrect you need to SET when assigning a value to a variable.

Comment: If `daftar_obat.kode_obat` is not primary/unque by according index then add `LIMIT 1` to `SELECT harga_obat INTO harga FROM daftar_obat WHERE kode_obat=NEW.kodeobat;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you want a *before* insert trigger so you can change the column value in the row.  Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER afterPembelian BEFORE INSERT ON pembelian
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE harga INT(20);
    DECLARE total INT(20);

    SELECT harga_obat INTO harga
    FROM daftar_obat o
    WHERE o.kode_obat = NEW.kodeobat;

    IF (DAYNAME(NEW.tanggal_pem) = 'Monday') THEN
        SET NEW.total = (harga  -harga / 10) * NEW.jml_beli;
    ELSE 
        SET NEW.total = harga * NEW.jml_beli;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: but I wanna show total and total isn't column. I'm trying but my trigger doesn't work again

Comment: @SylviaHelmi . . . You should ask another question for that issue.